# Limit of $\frac{2-|x|}{2+x}$ when $x\to -2$

Tags: calculus

- My problem: Find limit of$ (2-|x|)/(2+x)$ when $x \to (-2).$
- My solution:

$|x| = x$ ( when $x\geq  0$ ) and $|x| = -x $( when $x < 0 $)

Because $x \to (-2)$ $\Rightarrow$ $ 2 - |x| = 2 + x$

=> $$\lim_{x\to(-2)}\frac{2 - |x|}{2+x} = \lim_{x\to(-2)}\frac{2+x}{2+x} =\lim_{x\to-2} 1 = 1$$
Is that true ???

- And other problem: Find: $$\lim_{x\to 0-}\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{|x|}\right)$$
  My solution( because $x < 0$ ) : $$\lim_{x\to 0-}\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{|x|}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0-}\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x}\right) = 2\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{1}{x}$$

But $\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{1}{x}$ = ???. Help me solve it. Thanks.

Comment: "Is that true ???": yes. "Help me solve it": $\frac{1}{0^-}=-\infty$.

Comment: Have you drawn a graph of the function? Drawing a graph is not a proof, but it can reassure you that your calculations make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Your second problem:

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{|x|}\right)=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{x}-\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{|x|}=$$

---

Since $\lim_{x\to0^-}|x|$ and $|x|>0$ for all $x$ just to the left of $x=0$, 
$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{|x|}=\infty$.

Let $M>0$ and let $a=\frac{1}{m}$. Then $-\frac{1}{x}<-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{M}}=-M
$ for all $-a<x<0$.

Since $M$ can be chosen to be arbitrarily large, $\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty$

---

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{|x|}\right)=-\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

Your first solution seems to be correct. As for the second one, $\lim\limits_{x \to 0-}{\frac{1}{x}}=-\infty$.